# $C_1$ and $C_2$ are not necessarily isomorphic, although their groups are

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

> If the picard groups $Pic_K^0(C_1)$ and $Pic_K^0(C_2)$  associated to the curves $C_1, C_2$ are isomorphic (as abelian groups), then the curves are not necessarily isomorphic

I don't know if there are only counterexamples or a generalization why it does not hold, but the converse should be valid, i.e. if the curves are isomorphic, so their picard groups. (this is an exercise in elliptic curves)

In the book of Lawrence Washington (Elliptic Curves: Number Theory and Cryptography) the map, $Div^0(E)/(\text{principal divisors})\to E(\overline K)$ is called to be an isomorphism, in other sources only a bijection, which one is true ?

Comment: The theorem you are looking for is 'Torelli's theorem'. It says that if $C_1$ and $C_2$ are curves with $K$-points $p_1$ and $p_2$ and $\text{Pic}^0_K(C_1)$ and $\text{Pic}^0_K(C_2)$ are isomorphic as group schemes (you can think roughly, if you don't know about schemes, as saying that they're isomorphic by a group map which is also algebraic, this only works if $K=\overline{K}$ though) as principally polarized abelian varieties (scary, but this just means preserves the points $p_1$ and $p_2$) then the curves are isomorphic. Note if you want to work over not algebraically closed

Comment: you need to assume that the genii of the curves are at least $2$. But, since $E\cong \text{Pic}^0_K(E)$ (non-canonically) if $E$ is an elliptic curve, this takes care of the $g=1$ case. For $g=0$ it's bad since there are LOTS of genus $0$ curves over a not algebraically closed field (essentially something like the $2$-torsion of the Brauer group of the field, if that means something to you) but they all have trivial Picard scheme.

Comment: @AlexYoucis I believe the right plural is genera!

Comment: @Nesos The most fundamental of all mistakes! Thanks :)